# Why wasn't Hisoka interested in fighting Meruem?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Naturally, Hisoka seeks power, intelligence, and potential in an enemy. Meruem exceeds all Hisoka's targets in this regard.

Why didn't he show any interest (or even appear in the arc) in the king, the royal guards, or the chimera ants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Re-post:**
Because he had no clue that the ants even existed in the first place, Illumi informs him about the entire incident and its results at the start of the "gon restoration arc".

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same question and answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HunterXHunter/comments/4psxf6/where_was_hisoka_during_the_chimera_ant_arc/#ampf=undefined).

He basically didn't know of the ants' existence.